# gemspec extensions - conditionally install gem

Tags: ruby

I'm forking the gem and I'd like to add some conditional dependencies to gemspec file, depending on ruby version. I found that it could by done using spec.extensions. So in gem directory I created a file: ext/mkrf_conf.rb:

```
require 'rubygems/dependency_installer.rb' 
begin
   Gem::Command.build_args = ARGV
   rescue NoMethodError
end 
inst = Gem::DependencyInstaller.new


begin
    if RUBY_VERSION < "2.1.0"
        inst.install "activerecord", ">2.0", "< 4.0"
    else
        inst.install "activerecord", ">4.0"
    end
rescue
    exit(1)
end 

f = File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Rakefile"), "w")   # create dummy rakefile to indicate success
f.write("task :default\n")
f.close
```

Then I added the extension to gemspec file:

```
spec.extensions << 'ext/mkrf_conf.rb'
```

I created a test project, with Gemfile when I have:

```
gem 'my_gem', path: '/Users/xxx/Documents/my_projects/my_gem'
```

I'd like to test if this is work, but when I do bundle install, activerecord is not installing at all. As this extension is not exist. Can somebody can point me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be not an exact answer on your question, but I wonder whether you see that `Gemfile` is a plain ruby file. That said, you might simply drop your logic in your `Gemfile`:

```
if RUBY_VERSION < "2.1.0"
    gem "activerecord", ">2.0", "< 4.0"
else
    gem "activerecord", ">4.0"
end
gem ...
```

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: I've added this logic to gem's Gemfile. Still, during bundle install (in other project when I just require this gem), the activerecord is not installed as dependency :(

Comment: Then you should first make sure that `gem "activerecord", ">4.0"` works itself. I see at least one glitch within this code: you compare `RUBY_VERSION` string against other string with less operator, which won’t work; use integer `RUBY_REVISION` for comparision. Try to log what’s going wrong; being in `Gemfile` as is it must be executed.

Comment: Hmm, I did some tests and for ruby 2.0.0 the comparison RUBY_VERSION < "2.1.0" returns true. For ruby 2.1.3 it returns false, so I don't think this is a case. I also just put in Gemfile gem 'activerecord', '> 4.0' (also > 3.0) and still this dependency is not installed. Only if I put this dependency it gemspec, it is installed.

Comment: I tried with `bundle gem ggg && cd $_ && echo "gem 'activerecord', '> 4.0'" >> Gemfile && bundle install` and `activerecord` was successfully installed for me. Conditional above worked as well. This should be smth wrong with your environment (?). BTW, pls disregard my comment about version comparision; it surely works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well, this way of course is working. But I want that activerecord to be installed when I use this gem, so as a gem dependency. For gem development I can just declare activerecord as development_dependency in gemspec (this is more proper that do it in Gemfile).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: the gemspec is also pure ruby code. Did you try to put conditional there?

Comment: Yes and this is how it was written originally and this is a source of problem. When you put this logic to gemspec, it works as expected when you do bundle install in you gem locally. However, when you publish the gem to rubygems.org, rubygems doesn't support conditions in gemspec and just take first dependency version it found in gemspec. As a result, when somebody want to use your gem, dependencies might not be resolved correctly. There was a discussion about this: http://bit.ly/1DLucBD. Anyway, I think I'll create different versions of the gem. Thanks for support!